# Weird behavior of nosetest

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I try to use nose test
But when i run the testcase below

```
import unittest

class TestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    b = []

    def setUp(self):
        self.b.extend([10, 20])

    def tearDown(self):
        self.b = []

    def test_case_1(self):
        self.b.append(30)
        assert len(self.b) == 3
        assert self.b == [10, 20, 30]

    def test_case_2(self):
        self.b.append(40)
        assert len(self.b) == 3
        assert self.b == [10, 20, 40]
```

But all test cases is not pass

```
$> nosetest test_module.py
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_case_2 (test_module2.TestSuite)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/knt/test_module2.py", line 19, in test_case_2
    assert len(self.b) == 3
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

What 's happend ??? I expect after run test_case_1, tearDown will be called, so `self.b` is `[]`. So with next test case `test_case_2`, `setUp` run and `self.b` is `[10, 20]`.

But in fact, at `setUp` value of `self.b is [10, 20, 30]`.

I dont know why. I think there must be some problems with statement `self.b = []`.

Anything related pointers, I guess? 
I still didn't figure it out, but i find way to fix this bug. Just change `self.b = []` to `del self.b[:]`.

Anyone can help me find out the problem?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your class attribute in line 2:

```
b = []
```

That is an attribute on the class `TestSuite`. Nosetests creates a new instance of the class `TestSuite`, and then calls `setUp`. In `setUp`, you modify the **class** attribute on the class `TestSuite`:

```
self.b.extend([10, 20])
```

Then, in `tearDown`, after your first test has been run, you create a new list and assign it to a new **instance** attribute which is also happens to be called `b`:

```
self.b = []
```

This does not modify the **class** attribute at all. Further attempts to access `self.b` from this instance will return the **instance** attribute, not the class attribute.

But this has no effect, because the very next thing that happens is that nosetests throws away the current instance of `TestSuite`, including your new, empty list in the **instance** attribute `b` that you have set in `tearDown`.

Then nosetests creates a brand new instance of the class `TestSuite`, to run your second test. But the class `TestSuite` still has a `b` **class** attribute containing `[10, 20, 30]`, because it was modified while your first test was running.

Then nosetests `setUp` method runs, adds `10` and `20` to `TestSuite`'s **class** attribute `b`. Then your second test runs, adds `40` to `TestSuite`'s **class** attribute, and your second test fails, because it finds six items in that **class** attribute:

```
[10,20,30,10,20,40]
```

The reason that `del self.b[:]` works is because, just like `append`, `del` is modifying the **class** attribute, rather than creating a new **instance** attribute.

Make sure you understand the difference between classes and instances, and between class attributes and instance attributes, otherwise you will be plagued with similar problems for as long as you are working with Python.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell the problem maybe with the way unitests works and how class fields work in python here is a simple test:

```
class A:
    b = []
    def reset(self):
        self.b = []

a = A()    
a.b.append(3) # we are actually accessing the class variable here
print A.b is a.b # True
print a.b # [3] same here
a.reset() # We just hid the class variable with our own which points to []
print A.b is a.b # False as expected.
print a.b # [] we think its being clear but rather we are using our own not the class variable

b = A()
print b.b # [3] b here is using the class that a previously modified but is no longer pointing to
print b.b is A.b # True

# Also note
c = A()
d = A()
print c.b is d.b # True, since both are using the same class variable.
```

I think unittest is creating the object multiple times, for each test function, creates object, fires setup which access the class variable, the test runs, calls teardown which simply hides it, creates another object, calls setup which access the same class variable that the previous object modified and didn't affect since its tear down simply created a new instance binded to self, hiding the class version.

we always declare member fields inside the `__init__` using self.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.b = []
```

this way every instance will have its own copy, though we can't do this here since we are inheriting from `unittest.TestCase` thats why we have `setUp`

```
import unittest
class TestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.b = [10, 20]

    def tearDown(self):
        self.b = []

    def test_case_1(self):
        self.b.append(30)
        assert len(self.b) == 3
        assert self.b == [10, 20, 30]

    def test_case_2(self):
        self.b.append(40)
        assert len(self.b) == 3
        assert self.b == [10, 20, 40]
```

Comment: Thanks @samy.vilar, your explaination about class field is clear with me

Comment: @kiennt no problem, I wen through the same thing when I started out, the other subtle issue that gets people is default arguments &/| references `def test(key, values = {}); values[key] = 'test'; return values` some people think that every time you call `test` that values is will be set to `{}` but nope it only happens once during the initial definition of the function and since dicts are stored as reference the same dictionary will be used `every time` you call that function this may or may not be what you want, either way I hope you keep/enjoying python, its a great language ...

Comment: thanks again, your mention about default argument still new with me. Your help is very useful for me to understand python more clearly. And i also agree with you, python is great language :x

Comment: I was recently cauth in the same situation with nosetests, and I had external ``Game`` class where I declared class attribute ``rolls`` and then modifided it, and was wonderning, what is wrong! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to replace the:

```
self.b.extend([10,20])
```

with

```
self.b = [10,20]
```

and maybe throw out the class variable, you don't need it and it might be the reason this happens.

Comment: The problem in this case is not to passed all the test. What i wonder is how unittest works like that?